# Error intentando concatenar bits en Verilog

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module memoria_instruc(
input [7:0]index,
output reg [31:0] Inst
);

reg [7:0] memoria [0:255];
wire [15:0] cat1, cat2; //cables para asignar concatenacion

//asignar la concatenacion
assign cat1 = {memoria[index], memoria[index + 8'd1]}; 
assign cat2 = {memoria[index+8'd2], memoria[index + 8'd3]};

//secuencial para la salida 
always @(*)begin    
    Inst <= {cat1, cat2};
end

//asignar valores de inicio de la memoria 
initial begin 
memoria[0] = 8'B11111111;
memoria[1] = 8'B11111111;
memoria[2] = 8'B11111111;
memoria[3] = 8'B11111111;
end
endmodule
```

Necesito concatenar los datos de 4 direcciones de memoria, pero el operador de verilog para hacer esto, no esta funcionando correctamente, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: please translate your question, this is SO en español; otherwise it will be closed

Comment: Ya lo solucione debido a que crear un archivo de formato waveform es distinto a crear un testbench, se da ese tipo de error, que no se muestra el resultado esperado, recomiendo utilizar un testbench con modelsim-altera y se podrá observar que la salida si es correcta, gracias por leer, espero te haya ayudado en algo :)

Comment: La solución se pone como respuesta, no como comentario. Así es más fácil que otros lleguen y vean cómo lo resolviste (y que vean que está resuelta porque marcas tu respuesta como aceptada) :)